# SIZEOF() extension in Flang

Tags: fortran, llvm, sizeof, flang

Does anyone know whether the ["new" Flang](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/flang) LLVM Fortran frontend (available since LLVM 12) or the ["old"/"classic" Flang](https://github.com/flang-compiler/flang) compiler (based on PGI/NVIDIA) support the `SIZEOF()` function as a Fortran extension?
This inquiry function is [*not* in the Fortran standard](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/is-sizeof-standard-fortran/m-p/743976). A lot of compilers support it as an extension (not an exhaustive list): GFortran, Intel Fortran Classic (`ifort`), IBM XL Fortran, PGI (rest in pieces), NVIDIA HPC SDK.

Comment: Might be easiest to just try it (e.g. on godbolt.org)?

Comment: @Andrea It's not there for Fortran :/